# Ellipsis in PHP pagination issue

Tags: php, pagination, ellipsis

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
       $pageno = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
       $pageno = 1;
    }

    $getPages = "SELECT COUNT(steamid) FROM player_time";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($getPages, $sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
    $total_records = $row[0]; 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10); 
    $printed_ellipsis = false;

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 

        if($i > 4 && !$printed_ellipsis) 
        {
            echo "&hellip;"; //printing the ellipsis
            $i = max(0, $total_pages - 3);
            $printed_ellipsis = true;
        }

        if($i == $pageno)
        {
            echo "<span class='current-page'>$pageno</span>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<a class='paginations' href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
        }
    };
?>
```

**Output : 1 2 3 4 … 76 77 78 79**

When I reach the page 4, the 5,6,7,8.... don't appear. So basically I am stuck at page 4, without possibility of going to the fifth sixth and so on.

What's wrong here?

Comment: The code explicitly starts at 1, breaks at 4, and re-starts at length - 3.  What do you *want* to happen here?  When you get to page 4, what *should* the output look like?

Comment: Well, it should output the next numbers while the ones behind look like this: 1 ... 5, 6, 7, 8 ... 76, 77, 78, 79 . I see your point, but where should I start?

Comment: I'd start by modifying that `for` loop and that `if` condition which determines where in the pages you are.  That expected output is kind of strange, but I suppose it works.  You'll simply need to identify the patterns of output you expect and write that logic in the code.  Currently the logic explicitly starts at 1 and stops at 4, I imagine you'll want to change that.  Though I'm not sure what the pattern should be.

Comment: Well that was only one of the patterns I though of, the simplest pattern to create is the best for my needs. The only thing I was able to do while trying to fix it was to break the code.